# How to make query parameter list (multiple values) required at least one value in fastapi python framework

Tags: python, fastapi

I'am using fastapi framework and i want to send multiple values using Query like this .

```py
lst_name: Optional[List[str]] = Query(None).
```

so my question is how to make it required at least N values.

Comment: Everything you need to know (Query parameter list / multiple values; `min_length` parameter) is here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, do not use `None` and `Optional`.

```py
lst_name: List[str] = Query(...)
```

With **Ellipsis**: "`...`", you can make a parameter required.

Answer (score -1):

@yagiz Degirmenci's answer is correct, just to extend it if you want to force the list to have at least N number of elements you can use the parameter `min_length`

```py
    lst_name: List[str] = Query(..., min_length=N)
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, it will instead check that each item of the list is at least `N` char long.
See the documentation it specifically mentions that it validate the actual string: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=query%28#add-more-validations

There is an open Github issues that mention the confusion at the openapi level: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1629